# Sharepoint 2010 List Update through webservice throws error

Tags: web-services, list, sharepoint

I am trying to update a SharePoint 2010 list through web service. My code can successfully update any list on the ROOT level (or site collection level). It is only when i try to update any list on variation level that the application throws error "The list that is referenced here no longer exists.". 
Please keep in mind i have tried setting list.url property. Manually updated app.config. Any more ideas please share. My code:

```
        try
        {
            System.Xml.XmlNode ndListView = list.GetListAndView("{GUID}", "");
            string strListID = ndListView.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["Name"].Value;
            string strViewID = ndListView.ChildNodes[1].Attributes["Name"].Value;
            XmlElement xmlBatchElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");
            xmlBatchElement.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");
             xmlBatchElement.SetAttribute("OnError", "continue");
             xmlBatchElement.SetAttribute("ViewName", strViewID);
            xmlBatchElement.InnerXml = TheCaml; // TheCaml holds XML updates.
            try
            {
               XmlNode xmlReturn = list.UpdateListItems(strListID, xmlBatchElement);
```

// UpdateListItems gives error that the list does not exist anymore.

Comment: I tried list.getlistcollection() and it returns lists from the Root level only. What am i possibly doing wrong with the webservice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that i was using IP address  for the service reference whereas i should have been using server name instead of IP address.